# c# Socket send receive network

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm totally confused and stunned about my problem. I wrote a multi client server using sockets.

I created a first GUI that receives clients and display them in a gridview, in the click gridview event it opens a new GUI with the socket between the clicked client and the server. So everything about the connection between server and the clients go well and fast

But my problems are :

1. the send information between them like sending full process it sometimes shown full and it sometimes less result .
2. send files management for example when the server request full folders/files in a directory sometimes it shows them all and sometimes less result .

But the command such open a window open an url, send a message , commands like those works so perfectly and instantly .

I am so confused right now what's the problem

- Notice 1 : I used the extern IP for connection between server/client.
- Notice 2 : internet connection is perfect (definitely not slow)

I tried to use different buffer sizes, but what I'm really confused about is that sometimes the result comes full with a specific buffer size and sometimes not with the same buffer size .

Thank you for your time !

Comment: What protocol did you use? See, http protocol use **Content-Length** for packet-size detect. You must transfer packet-size information, and read packet header first (with limit size), and than other path of packet.

Comment: first thank you for your reply, so  I use tcp with stream socket type and internetwork card i didint fully understand your comment

Comment: You must transfer packet length first. See http specification for example.

Comment: lets say for example i have a function that transfer a all the executed processes so i need to collect all the sizes of those process first then send them after ?

Comment: Yes, and size of message also add to the packet. For example: `struct S{ int size; char data[1] } s; send(s, datasize + sizeof(int))`,  then datasize=Read(sizeof(int))  and Read(datasize)

Comment: Then make buffer size the same as the sent data size then receive it , so that i won't loose data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also recommend you use wireshark so that you are able to get the full information and transactions that are really going on in the network.

This will help you to rule out where the issue is coming from.

To determine the packet size see the image [image]

Here I am not talking about how the TCP handshaking protocol works as I assume it is working. However do note that in the transmission if you see something like RST then maybe somebody issued a reset command implying that some error occurred in the transmission. Such as something due to checksum for example. Although it is generally a problem for someone working directly on TCP/IP protocol

This should help you confirm that you sent and recieved the correct length.

Comment: Hi ! , can you describe a bit how can he detect the packet size ?

Comment: hi i have updated my answer. Please ask me any question if you have any that i can assist with. give me an upvote too if you like my answer!